Rudin $7.6$ Lebesgue points.
There is the definition of Lebesgue points: If $f \in L^{1}(\Bbb R^{k})$, any $x \in \Bbb R^{k}$ for which it is true that
$$ \lim_{r\to 0}  \frac{1}{m(B_r)} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y) - f(x)|\  dm(y) = 0$$
is called a Lebesgue point of $f$.
He also states that it holds if $f$ is continuous at the point $x$.
I don't understand why does it necessarily holds.
Any help would be appreciated.

The expression is less than $\sup_{y,,|y-x|\le r}|f(y)-f(x)|.$

This is clear from the definition of ''continuous at $x$.'' Here is the reason:
Because $f$ is continuous at $x$, for any given $\varepsilon>0,$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $y\in B_\delta(x).$
Then (as $r<\delta$) we have
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{m(B_r)} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y) - f(x)|\  dm(y)
&< \frac{1}{m(B_r)}\cdot \varepsilon\cdot\int_{B(x,r)}\  dm(y)\\
&=\varepsilon\cdot\frac{m(B_r)}{m(B_r)}=\varepsilon
\end{split}
$$
Hence
$$\lim_{ r\to 0} \frac{1}{m(B_r)} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y) - f(x)|\  dm(y) = 0$$
